# Anime with commando bunnies

Tags: cat-shit-one

I saw a few images of this anime.

It was based in Afghanistan, or some place similar. Except of humans fighting terrorists, it was bunnies. The bunnies were dressed like soldiers.

I think it was supposed to be a tongue in cheek parody of the war, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The show you are looking for is called "[Cat Shit One](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11444)"

[image]

It's based on a manga of the same name (and also called [Apocalypse Meow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_Meow) in the U.S.). As far as I know, there's only been one episode and it's mostly CG animated. The terrorists are all camels.

Comment: From what I've heard, each country gets its own animal. Americans are rabbits because "USA G.I." => usagi (rabbit).